# Android - create and transfer file from Android device to a usb stick programmatically

Tags: android, linux, usb, root

I would like to write an Android program that will create a text file on my Nexus 7 (2013) tablet and then transfer it to my connected USB stick (it is connected through an OTG cable). My device is rooted, and I thought that I would be able to do this by executing basic linux commands.

I was planning to invoke linux commands using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls")` (ls could be replaced by another linux command). Does anyone know if this approach will work, or is there a better way to get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Stock android does not support usb mass storage devices.  But if your device is root-hacked you might be able to mount it.  Normally on a stock, secured device you have to implement mass storage and a filesystem in application code on top of the usb host apis.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about that? Also, do you know why it isn't as easy as changing the current directory to the one corresponding to the USB device?

Comment: Because android is not designed to support usb sticks or custom mounts in general at operating system level.

Comment: Yeah, but since I'm doing this on a rooted device, I should be able to access the folder, right?